# Laravel conditional eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm developing an application where a User can be of type Admin, Client, Supplier or Manager. Each type (except Admin) has it's own model with respective data, and related with a user_id. For example:

```
users
    - id
    - name
    - email
    - password
    - type

clients
    - id
    - user_id
    - segment
    - last_buy

suppliers
    - id
    - user_id
    - product_type
    - corporate_name

managers
    - id
    - user_id
    - managed_area
```

I want to have, in my `User` model, a `profile` attribute that loads user's data from it's other model (Client, Supplier or Manager), based on existing `type` attribute.

Before, I've used the `$appends` property and `getProfileAttribute()` method approach to achieve the result. But now, I'm trying to optimize my application using eager loading. So I'm trying to load the profile this way:

```php
public function profile(){
    if($this->type == "client"){
        return $this->hasOne(Client::class);
    } else if($this->type == "supplier"){
        return $this->hasOne(Supplier::class);
    } else if($this->type == "manager"){
        return $this->hasOne(Manager::class);
    }
    return null;
}
```

But isn't working. Every query `->with(["profile"])` returns the `profile` attribute with null value. I've `dd`ed the `$this->type` and noticed is always returning null too. I don't understood why, but this is the cause why it can't conditionally check User's type.

So how can I achieve the expected result?

Comment: What you are trying to do is close to being a morph in Laravel, here it is required that id and type is in the same table to make that work, are you able to change the code or? and the reasoning for your code not working is when queries are executed before model load, $this->type will always be null, so your approach is not feasible.

Comment: Do you have relationships set correctly on all models? I think not. Show the contents of the Users, Clients, Suppliers, Managers Models.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify a *foreign key* and *local key* for each *hasOne* because you are not using 'conventional' column names.

e.g.:

```
$this->hasOne(Client::class, 'id', 'user_id');
```

Comment: OP *is* using conventional names ... ? The parent users table has an `id`, and each of the child tables has a `user_id`.

Answer (score 0):

As @mrhn commented above, the reason for your code not working is when queries are executed before model load. You can consider to apply One To One (Polymorphic) in your code: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations

Your tables would be:

```
users
    - id
    - name
    - email
    - password
    - profile_type
    - profile_id

clients
    - id
    - segment
    - last_buy

suppliers
    - id
    - product_type
    - corporate_name

managers
    - id
    - managed_area
```

Your migration:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->morphs('profile');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Your relationship in user model:

```
/**
 * Get the user's profile;.
 */
public function profile()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```